# Ansible variables from script

Tags: ansible

Id like to populate ansible variables from a script that generated whenever a play is done. in particular, ive written something that uses an api somewhere to get users in a group on an application. Id like this to be run locally, and form the group vars for a play.

Script output:

```
users:
    user1: jsmith
        ssh_key: .......
    user2: fsmith
        ssh_key: .......
```

Is there a way to use dynamic variables? Something akin to dynamic inventory?

p.s. the first line of the output was '---' but I dont know how to get that to show here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically define variables within a play using `set_fact`: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/set_fact_module.html

Now for your use-case, imho, it would be better if your script returns a json result as it would be easier to parse using jinja filters